# Which site is appropriate to ask for keyboard recommendations?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, keyboard

I would find it appropriate in both stackoverflow and superuser. However, I'm guessing others may find that a big no-no. So, which site is a good place to discuss this ?

(For the curious, I want a keyboard with the form factor of the old IBM style, but quiet.)

Comment: Google is the appropriate site for looking for a keyboard reviews.

Comment: One problem with product recommendations is that they attract a lot of link only comments/answers and it's nearly impossible to tell whether a recommendation is honest or spam. Now go check out [Das Keyboard](http://www.daskeyboard.com/), bit pricey, but I think it's close to what you're looking for (honest or spam? you tell me ;).

Comment: @YannisRizos - Thank you - I'm typing on a dasKeyboard "silent" right now. It's quite noisy (otherwise perfect).

Answer (score 15):

[It would not be appropriate on any stack exchange site.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Reading that link it looks like a question that lays out a very specific set of criteria on SuperUser would be ok. Or am I not understanding something there?

Comment: @DavidThielen No, it wouldn't.  If at the end of the day you're asking for someone to give you a product then it's not appropriate on this site.  If you're asking a question that won't be answered with a product (i.e. how do I judge whether or not a keyboard that I'm considering won't have problem X) then it *might* have a shot.

Comment: I'm not following this. Accroding to the link "Q: What’s the best low light point-and-shoot camera?" is a valid question for SuperUser. By that measure, wouldn't "What is the quietest classic IBM style keyboard?" be acceptable by that measure? What am I missing that makes the one ok but not the other?

Comment: @DavidThielen The first one is an example of what **not** to ask.  The second is a re-phrasing of the previous question in a way that would be acceptable on SE.

Answer (score 7):

None, but I think that you could try in chat. It's the best place also because there you can actually discuss.